# formula of derivative at a point with t and t-1 is OK?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I want to calculate the speed of my robot moving far away from a wall (that distance to my robot can be measured by a sensor)
so the speed at time t is
$$\frac{distance_{t}-distance_{t-1}}{\Delta T} (1) $$ with $\Delta T$ is the sampling time and small enough.

however, as i know the derivative at a point t is:
$$lim\frac{f_{t+\Delta T}-f_{t}}{\Delta T}$$

Am I calculating the speed of the time t-1 instead of t with (1)? I could not get distance at t+1 at time t. How can I calculate the speed at time t?

P/S: i am confused to know if it should be at robotics or mathematics. I think mathematics is more proper.

Answer (score 1):

I think your are misunderstanding formula (1). Assuming that you are taking measurements at times $t_0, t_1, t_2, \cdots$, formula (1) should read
$$
f'(t_i) \approx \dfrac{d(t_{i+1})-d(t_i)}{t_{i+1}-t_i}.
$$

There is no $t-1$... just the previous time step. You can use other approximations, for instance

$$
f'(t_i) \approx \dfrac{d(t_i)-d(t_{i-1}}{t_i-t_{i-1}}
$$

or

$$
f'(t_i)\approx \dfrac{d(t_{i+1})-d(t_{i-1}}{2(t_{i+1}-t_{i-1})}
$$

Comment: Thanks. so assume $t_{i}-t_{i-1}=\Delta T$, my speed is $\frac{d(t_{i})-d(t_{i-1})}{\Delta T}$ with $d(t_{i})$ is the current measurement at time $t_{i}$ and $d(t_{i-1})$ is the last measurement at time $t_{i-1}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The last formula behaves better in most cases, as the error is $O(\Delta T^2)$ while in the other cases the error is $O(\Delta T)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ vastly  overestimates the speed if $\Delta T\to 0$. Instead, use $$\frac{ d(t) -d(t-1)}{t-(t-1)} =d(t) -d(t-1)  $$ to get the *average* speed over the time interval $[t,t+1]$. To get the exact speed at $t$, you must take a limit, or the derivative: $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{d(t+h) -d(t)}{h} $$

Comment: So it means in my case I cannot get the speed at time t (because the sensor could not measure the distance at time t+1 (it is future))?

Comment: @abcd Of course you can. Just let $h\to 0^-$ in the limit. So you will need the distance at $t$ and the distance some time before $t$.

Comment: you mean if the $\Delta T$ in my (1) is small enough? it is constant for every sampling time

Comment: @abcd That’s ok. The smaller it is, the better the accuracy.

Comment: @Tavish It does not necessarily overestimate the derivative... That depends entirely on $d(t)$, you can come up with examples going either way.

Comment: @PierreCarre Okay, it does if $d(t)$ is strictly increasing.